# lmm_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(lmm_image)[0] IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import face_recognition
import cv2

input_movie = cv2.VideoCapture("ruangan1.mp4")
length = int(input_movie.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
print()

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
output_movie = cv2.VideoWriter('output3.avi', fourcc, 30, (1920, 1080))

lmm_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("wajah_depan_syahdan.jpg")
lmm_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(lmm_image)[0]

known_faces = [
    lmm_face_encoding
]
```

I got error says:

```
lmm_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(lmm_image)[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Is the error about element 1 of the list, as in your title, or about element 0 of the list, as in your code?

Comment: @BoarGules it is about element 0 of the list, sorry for the typo

Comment: What the error message is telling you is that `face_recognition.face_encodings(lmm_image)` is returning an empty list. At this point in your shoes I would consult the documentation for that function to find out under what circumstances the function does that.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (len( face_recognition.face_encodings(
image_to_be_matched))> 0):
   print("face found in image!")
   '''continue'''
else:
    print('Face Not found')
    '''Do Something Else or repeat capture'''


#I think this Will help You!
```